# how to validate DateTimePickerModal with yup and formik in React native?

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker, formik, yup

Here is my screen component with two textinputs from the link. I have removed some other code that isn't necessary to this issue.
When i choose the date from the popup it appears in the text input but doesnt get validated.
I cannot use the result of DatePicker component as it is , so i am doing some formating and saved to a function getDate.

How would you go about implemnting this ? is there any better way

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43dCq.png)

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  Image,


} from 'react-native';

import { icons, COLORS, } from '../constants';

import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from "yup";

import client from '../api/client';
  
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";



const addfarm = ({ navigation, Arrival_Date }) => {

const addFarmValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  Farm_Code: yup.string().required('Please Enter the chick price'),
 Arrival_Date: yup.string().required('Please Choose a date'),

});

  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    hideDatePicker();
    setDate(date);

  };


  const getDate = () => {
    let tempDate = JSON.stringify(date).split(/[ ",T,]/);
    return date !== ''
      ? `${tempDate[1]}`
      : '';


  };


  const newDate = getDate();

  const addFarmInfo = {
    Farm_Code: '',
    Arrival_Date: '',

  };


  const add = async (values) => {
    const res = await client({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/Farm/SaveFarm',
      data: JSON.stringify({ ...values, id })
    })
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  return (

    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={addFarmInfo}
          validateOnMount={true}
          onSubmit={add}
          validationSchema={addFarmValidationSchema}>
          {({
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            values,
            touched,
            errors,
            isValid,
            setFieldValue,
          }) => {

            const {
              Farm_Code,
              Arrival_Date,

            } = values

            return (

              <View
                style={{
                  paddingHorizontal: '10%',
                  paddingTop: 50,
                  marginTop: 50,
                  backgroundColor: COLORS.main_background,
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.auth_text}>Add Farm</Text>


                <Text style={styles.tag}>
                  Farm Code:
                </Text>
                <View
                  style={[styles.textInputView, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>
                  <TextInput
                    onChangeText={handleChange('Farm_Code')}
                    onBlur={handleBlur('Farm_Code')}
                    value={Farm_Code}
                    placeholder="Farm Code"
                    placeholderTextColor={COLORS.placeholder_fonts}
                    selectionColor={COLORS.drawer_button}
                    style={styles.textInput}

                  />

                  <Image
                    source={!errors.Farm_Code ? icons.tick : icons.close}
                    resizeMode="stretch"
                    style={{
                      width: 18,
                      height: 18,
                      tintColor: !errors.Farm_Code ? COLORS.drawer_button : 'red',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      marginRight: 10,
                    }}
                  />

                </View>
                {(errors.Farm_Code && touched.Farm_Code) &&
                  <Text style={styles.errors}>{errors.Farm_Code}</Text>
                }





                <Text style={styles.tag}>
                  Arrival Date:
                </Text>

                <View
                  style={[styles.textInputView, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>

                  <TextInput
                    onChangeText={handleChange('Arrival_Date')}
                    onBlur={handleBlur('Arrival_Date')}
                    value={newDate}
                    onFocus={showDatePicker}
                    placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"
                    placeholderTextColor={COLORS.placeholder_fonts}
                    selectionColor={COLORS.drawer_button}
                    style={styles.textInput}

                  />




                  <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginRight: 10, }}
                    onPress={showDatePicker}

                  >
                    <DateTimePickerModal
                      isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
                      mode="date"
                      onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                      onCancel={hideDatePicker}
                    />

                    <Image
                      source={icons.calendar}
                      resizeMode="stretch"
                      style={{
                        width: 18,
                        height: 18,
                        tintColor: COLORS.secondary_fonts,
                        alignItems: 'center'
                      }}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>


                  <Image
                    source={!errors.Arrival_Date ? icons.tick : icons.close}
                    resizeMode="stretch"
                    style={{
                      width: 18,
                      height: 18,
                      tintColor: !errors.Arrival_Date ? COLORS.drawer_button : 'red',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      marginRight: 10,
                    }}
                  />

                </View>

                {(errors.Arrival_Date && touched.Arrival_Date) &&
                  <Text style={styles.errors}>{errors.Arrival_Date}</Text>
                }


                {(errors.Arrival_Date && touched.Arrival_Date) &&
                  <Text style={styles.errors}>{errors.Arrival_Date}</Text>
                }


                {/* Save */}
                <TouchableOpacity
                  disabled={!isValid}
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                  style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: isValid ? COLORS.authButtons : COLORS.placeholder_fonts, marginTop: 10 }]}>
                  <Text style={styles.button_Text}>Save</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )
          }
          }
        </Formik >
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>


  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.main_background,
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    color: 'black',
  },
  auth_text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  button: {
    height: 50,
    width: '100%',
    marginVertical: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button_Text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: COLORS.white,
  },
  login_nav: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '400',
    marginTop: 10,

  },
  errors: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: '400',
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  textInputView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 50,
    width: '100%',
    borderColor: COLORS.secondary_fonts,

  },



  tag: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 4,
    marginLeft: 4
  },

});

export default addfarm;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want formik to handle the validation, you should call the `setFieldValue` method and it will trigger the validation [as the documentation says](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void)

Comment: setFieldValue did not trigger the validation . Do i need to change something in the yup validation schema . handlefield was called in onChangeText iin the TextInput.`code`  const handlefield = () => {

              setFieldValue('Arrival_Date', newDate)

            };

Comment: Anyway what i actually ended up doing was that i removed date picker component from formik and made custom error when its not filled